# Incremental search: is it possible to push 'Esc` without scrolling back?

Tags: search, navigation

My problem on this gif:

[image: vim incremental search, theme Gotham, macOS, term]

I am in one place, searching for `meta`, I do not want to loose my current search highlighting (yes I know that I can restore it later in `/` menu). I found what I need - without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I want to stay here, without autoscrolling back to my original position.

Comment: what's wrong with pressing `Enter` after you found what you were looking for and finished your search input?

Comment: I do not want to loose my current search highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible in Vim, but I'm ready to be surprised.

The only idea I have is to create a mapping to set the last search to the next to last search. So you hit `<Enter>` and then use the mapping to reset your search highlighting.

```
nnoremap _ps :let @/=histget('/',-2)<CR>
```

If you want to drop the last search entirely, you could define the mapping as

```
nnoremap _ps :call histdel('/',-1)\|let @/=histget('/',-1)<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this mapping & function to do this:

```
function! KeepCursorEsc() abort
  let g:search_pos = getcurpos()
  return "\<C-C>:call setpos('.', g:search_pos)\<CR>"
endfunction

cnoremap <expr> <silent> <Esc> KeepCursorEsc()
```

### How it works

We can't use an regular `cmap` because we need to run code while the search is still active. Instead we use an expression mapping, which allows us to run a function by evaluating it as an expression.

The function first reads the cursor position with `getcurpos()` and then returns a string which is used as the `rhs` of the mapping.

This `rhs` cancels the search with `<C-C>` (`<Esc>` used in a `cmap` [runs the search command instead of cancelling it](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_Esc)) and then restores the cursor position to what it was when the mapping was invoked by calling `setpos()`.

N.B. Note that the function will also be called when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> while typing a `:` command. We should really avoid this by checking the type of the command-line with `getcmdtype()`, but for simplicity, this answer does not do so: when you're typing a `:` command the cursor will be in the same position anyway, so the function won't move it unexpectedly!

Comment: We had very [similar ideas](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/1ef979aee5bc0b34c074247e30897105). Although I used a self clearing `CmdlineLeave` event to restore the position

Comment: @PeterRincker Nice! That seems like a cleaner way of doing it than what I’m doing.